# Draw a plot for more than one column

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R Programming i want to draw a plot for more than one column from the dataset.

For example 
This is my sample code 
here i added more dataset i want to combine all values in one graph . How could i combine this?

```
stock_apple<-read.csv(file="apple.csv",header = TRUE,sep=",")
stock_microsoft<-read.csv(file="microsoft.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
stock_google<-read.csv(file="google.csv",header = TRUE,sep=",")
stock_twitter<-read.csv(file="twitter.csv",header = TRUE,sep=",")

var1<-stock_apple$high
var2<-stock_google$high
var3<-stock_microsoft$high
var4<-stock_twitter$high

install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

#this is for only one column but i want a plot for more than one column 
qplot(var1,
      geom="histogram",
      binwidth = 0.5,  
      main = "Histogram for Apple stock_price", 
      xlab = "stock price",  
      fill=I("blue"), 
      col=I("red"), 
      alpha=I(.2),
      xlim=c(100,3000))
```

Comment: Please post: `head(var1)` and `head(var2)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a plot for more than one column. Hope it helps you.

```
k <- 1000
set.seed(1)
dts1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(k,1000,100), y=rnorm(k,1800,100),z=rnorm(k,2600,100))
dts2 <- reshape::melt(dts1)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dts2, aes(x=value,fill=variable)) +
geom_histogram(color="white", alpha=.7, binwidth = 50) +
labs(x="Stock price",title="Histogram for Apple stock_price")+
xlim(c(100,3000))
```

[image]

Using `qplot`:

```
qplot(x=value, fill=variable, data=dts2,
      geom="histogram",
      binwidth = 50,  
      main = "Histogram for Apple stock_price", 
      xlab = "Stock price",  
      alpha=I(.7),
      colour=I("white"),
      xlim=c(100,3000))
```